# Laravel Unit Test method execpted from a filter gives error argument #2 is not an array

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit

I am trying to unit test by laravel here is the situation
I have a controller ArticlesController in which I have the auth filter to all of the controller's method except getShow method

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => 'getShow'));
}
```

and here is the method

```
public function getShow($id){
    return View::make('articles.show', array('article'=>Article::find($id)));
}
```

and here is my testing code

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

/**
 * A basic functional test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testBasicExample()
{
    Route::enableFilters();
    $response = $this->call('GET', 'articles/show/1');
    $this->assertViewHas('article');
}
```

}

but I when I run the test from the cmd I get this error

> ErrorException: array_replace_recursive(): Argument #2 is not an array

**NOTE: When I remove the method from the auth filter exception I don't get this error

but when I remove the filter from the whole controller the error appears again**

Comment: Now I'm sure that it has something to do with the database. I observed that this error comes whenever the test executes a function that connects with a database `Article::find($id) || Auth::attempt(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the database configurations I didn't know that the database configurations for testing must be defined even if you already have defined the configurations of your app database.
I simply created a file **database.php** in this directory **app/config/testing/**
and put the configurations for the database

```
// app/config/testing/database.php

<?php

return array(

'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'laravel',
        'username'  => 'MY_USER_NAME',
        'password'  => 'MY_PASSWORD',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
)
);
```